# How to fix the footer after content of the page in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, this

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="push"></div>
      <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
          <p class="muted credit">
          <center class='muted copyright'>
      <span>HALL-APP</span>
    <br/>
    <span>&copy; mmxiiiv &middot; Innologiq <br/>
    Dharwad, Karnataka, India.
    </span></center>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <style type="text/css">


      html,
          body {
            height: 100%;
            /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
          }

          /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
          #wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;
            /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
            margin: 0 auto -110px;
             padding: 0 0 60px;
          }

          /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
          #push,
          #footer {
           /*  height: 60px; */
            /* position: relative;
              margin-top: -150px; negative value of footer height
              height: 150px;
              clear:both;
              padding-top:20px;
              bottom:0; */


            bottom: 0px;
            height: 80px;
            left: 0;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
          }


          /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
          @media (max-width: 767px) {
            #footer {
              margin-left: -20px;
              margin-right: -20px;
              padding-left: 20px;
              padding-right: 20px;
            }
          }



          /* Custom page CSS
          -------------------------------------------------- */
          /* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */
    This CSS is for the content of the page
          .container {
            width: auto;
            max-width: 680px;
          }
          .container .credit {
            margin: 20px 0;
          }enter code here

    </style>
     <!-- Part 1: Wrap all page content here -->
```

I have used this code for the footer purpose,now i want fix the footer how can i do,Please suggest me what all changes to be done for the following code.This code fix the footer  but content of the page overlap the footer how to overcome this problem

Comment: Add <div class="clearfix"></div> after your content but before the footer

Comment: @PeteTNT I have added the <div class="clearfix"></div> staring of the footer but still its not working properly,Please suggest me different code

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?? so fix will be easy

Comment: one more thing i am not clear on your requirement, explain little bit more.